# Search for a string in a line and replace the entire line with another string

Tags: python

I have a file called `testing` present in `/home/hiperbolt` that has a line which says:

```
nameserver 127.89.87.3
```

I want a piece of code to look for a line that starts with `nameserver` and replace the entire line with

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

What currently happens with my code is that it only replaces the nameserver part so it becomes:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 127.89.87.3
```

instead of

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without regex if you wanted.

```
with open('/home/hiperbolt', 'r') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('nameserver'):
            lines.append('nameserver 8.8.8.8')
        else:
            lines.append(line)

with open('/home/hiperbolt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `re.sub()` on the text content of the file, and then write the replaced text back to the file.

```
In [30]: filedata
Out[30]: 'nameserver 127.89.87.3\nsearch example.com\n'

In [31]: re.sub(r'nameserver\s+.*', 'nameserver 8.8.8.8', filedata)
Out[31]: 'nameserver 8.8.8.8\nsearch example.com\n'
```